# Powershell to C# - Dynamic Objects

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamic

I'm running a Powershell script in c# that returns a collection of PSObjects.  The only way I have been able to see the underlying properties I need is by using dynamic as below.  This works on the computer I wrote the code on.

```
foreach (dynamic result in results)
    {
         if (result.PropertyName != null)
         {
             //do something  
         }
   }
```

However, on any other computer I've tried to run it on, as soon as I try to access any of the properties, I get a RuntimeBinderException "does not contain a definition for."  I can see all of the properties in the debugger however.

It looks like the problem is along the lines of what's described here: http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic

I'm at a loss on how to apply that to the issue I'm seeing though (new to programming\c# and this is the first time I'm trying anything with the DLR).

Comment: How are the objects created in PowerShell? (Ie. would looking at [`PSObject.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.psobject.properties(v=vs.85).aspx) and directly using PowerShells "Extended Type System" be a better approach?)

Comment: Are the other computers running PowerShell V3?  @Richard, ETS is fine to use from PowerShell script but in C#, using dynamic is easier. :-)

Comment: Thanks Keith - I feel silly, PowerShell V3 install was the solution.

Comment: Yeah, only v3 psobjects implement the dynamic meta object provider.